# Jasmine-Protractor Rest Call

Tags: rest, jasmine

I am trying to make a rest call to an oAuth server to get a token to serve as input to my Jasmine test. Now, I was assuming that I would be able to do this with XMLHttpRequest.

But when I run the test I get an error saying

> "Message:Failed: XMLHttpRequest is not defined"
>   ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined

This is for the part of the code which errors out `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();`

Any idea what's going wrong here, or is there a better way to do this? I see a lot of articles which talk about XMLHttpRequest in context of mock objects, but I am not trying to mock this cuz I need a token to be returned by the server.

The code I am using is here -->

```
    var data = "someData";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'someAuth');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', '*/*');
    xhr.open("POST", url);
    xhr.send(data);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this could happen due to two reasons:

1. You have not installed XMLHttp, which can be done using node package manager with the following command:

   ```
   npm install xmlhttprequest
   ```

More details here --> [XMLHTTP INSTALL LINK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest)

2. If you already had installed xmlhttprequest, the issue then could be because the editor is not able to get the environment variables. This had happened to me when I ran into this issue. I was using WebStorm on Mac, which would not use the environment variables from my system. To over come this, I launched the editor from Terminal and then xmlhttpRequest was recognized in my code.